# TestNG test results not showing in Eclipse Result window

Tags: eclipse, testng

I've been using TestNG for a very short time. I'm having an annoying issue:

When running a certain test class, the Results window does not show any results, although the console clearly states that the tests passed. Does anybody know of such an error or why this would happen?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I have never personally faced the issue.  Is it a specific class giving issues or is it random?  If it is specific to a class..probably you can share the code of that class and how you are triggering the run, for someone to be able to help you out..

Comment: Were you able to resolve this?  I am getting similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

I am able to resolve This problem by un selecting the use Project Testng Jar.

Go to Project Properties -> TestNg  and unselect use Project testng jar option and run again (build the project before that ).